# NLog environment variable config files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm stuck on this kinda simple problem. I'm trying to make multiple nlog config files, so that nlog can load them depending on environment variable.
I've added `nlog.debug.config`, `nlog.production.config`, and changed `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to corresponding value,  but no luck so far. I guess it's not that simple. I could set it up inside Startup.cs file, like this:

```
env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.environment.config");
```

But is there some automatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` to get environment name and build file name at runtime:

```
env.ConfigureNLog($"nlog.{env.EnvironmentName}.config");
```

and don't forget about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but NLog provides a standard way to do this as well.  The .NET Core `appsettings.json` file is already environment specific, and you can configure NLog within these files.

For example, in `appsettings.Staging.json` you could have one `"NLog"` element and a different setting in `appsettings.Production.json`.

Here is [the documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#loading-from-appsettingsjson).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70945815/193178

Answer (score 0):

NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.9.3 adds support for loading the NLog.config that matches the environment-variable using `LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()`.

It will automatically load from `nlog.Production.config` depending on environment variable `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`.

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration